# logic to break 10 to 115 with spacing of 10 java

Tags: java, loops

I have the following values:

int startIndex=10;
int maxResultCount = 115;

The above suggests that there will be a total of 115 starting from index 10 and ending to 125.

So I need to generate a sequence of startIndex and endIndex with a spacing of 10.

Like:

```
startIndex       endIndex
   10               20
   21               30
   31               40
   41               50
   51               60 
   61               70 
   71               80
   81               90 
   91               100
   101              110 
   111              120 
   121              125
```

the main problem is with the last excess 5 records. (121 - 125). I am not able the get that last row. I have done the below code:

```
    int startIndex= 10;
    int maxResultCountCount = 115;
    int endIndex = 0;
    int tempStartIndex=startIndex;

        endIndex = startIndex + 10;
        while(endIndex < tempStartIndex + maxResultCountCount){
                System.out.println(startIndex);
                    System.out.println(endIndex);
                    System.out.println();
            startIndex = endIndex + 1;
            endIndex =  (endIndex + 10 > tempStartIndex + maxResultCountCount) ? (tempStartIndex + maxResultCountCount) : (endIndex + 10);

        }
```

I am getting the following result with the above code:

```
10
20

21
30

31
40

41
50

51
60

61
70

71
80

81
90

91
100

101
110

111
120
```

As you can see I am losing the last 5 records (121 - 125).

Please help me with a correct logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do ..!!

```
int startIndex= 10;
int maxResultCountCount = 115;
int endIndex = 0;
int spacing=10;
int maxValue=maxResultCountCount+startIndex;
int endIndex =endIndex+spacing;
while(startIndex < maxValue){
        System.out.println(startIndex+"              "+endIndex);
        startIndex = endIndex + 1;
        endIndex =  endIndex+spacing;
        if(endIndex>maxValue)
            endIndex=maxValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    while(endIndex < tempStartIndex + maxResultCountCount){
            System.out.println(startIndex);
                System.out.println(endIndex);//here first print value than increase at last
                System.out.println();
        startIndex = endIndex + 1;
        endIndex =  (endIndex + 10 > (tempStartIndex + maxResultCountCount)) ? (tempStartIndex + maxResultCountCount) : (endIndex + 10);
//when its return 125 than condition should be false so achive this print the value outside the loop

    }
    System.out.println(startIndex);
    System.out.println(endIndex);
```

Comment: thanks bro...this is working but I marking the below as the correct answer because the no. of lines of code is getting reduced in my case. Thanks a lot....

Comment: @saptarshi does'nt mattter